# Angular version issue

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a older version of Ionic project. When I run the ionic project I get the following error:

```
[ng] This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions 0.0.0 || ^9.0.0-beta || >=9.0.0 <10.0.0,
[ng] but Angular version 12.1.5 was found instead.
```

When I list my global installed packages (npm ls -g --depth=0), I get the following result:

```
+-- @angular/cli@9.1.15 <------------- Version is 9.1.15
+-- cordova@10.0.0
+-- cordova-res@0.15.3
+-- firebase-tools@9.20.0
+-- ionic@5.2.0
`-- typescript@4.4.4
```

When I list the packages in my application directory (npm ls --depth=0), I get the following result:

```
+-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.901.15
+-- @angular/cli@9.1.15 <------------- Version is 9.1.15
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY @angular/common@9.1.13
+-- @angular/compiler@9.1.13
+-- @angular/compiler-cli@9.1.13
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY @angular/core@9.1.13
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY @angular/forms@9.1.13
+-- @angular/language-service@9.1.13
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser@9.1.13
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@9.1.13
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY @angular/router@9.1.13
.......
```

When I list using ng --version in my project folder, this is what I get:

```
Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.15
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.15
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.15
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.15
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.15
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.15
@angular/cli                      9.1.15 <------------- Version is 9.1.15
@angular/compiler                 9.1.13
@angular/compiler-cli             9.1.13
@angular/fire                     5.4.2
@angular/language-service         9.1.13
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.15
@schematics/angular               9.1.15 <------------- Version is 9.1.15
@schematics/update                0.901.15
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.8.3
webpack                           4.42.0
```

I ran ng --version in root folder (D:), and this is what I got:

```
D:\>ng --version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 9.1.15 <------------- Version is 9.1.15
Node: 14.16.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular:
...
Ivy Workspace:

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.901.15
@angular-devkit/core         9.1.15 <------------- Version is 9.1.15
@angular-devkit/schematics   9.1.15
@schematics/angular          9.1.15 <------------- Version is 9.1.15
@schematics/update           0.901.15
rxjs                         6.5.4
```

I am now totally confused on where the Angular version 12.1.5 is coming from. All my listing shows Angular Cli has 9.1.15

Can anyone guide, where to look for version 12.1.5 of angular?

Comment: Try to run ng --version out of your project angular folder, and see if you have another global version of @schematics/angular (the v12.1.5)

Comment: Thanks @JuanVicenteBerzosaTejero. I ran ng --version in my project folder. That is the third list given in the question. Let me edit the question to clarify that.

Comment: @Shudhir,I actually understood well and I knew you ran it in your project folder. But I was asking for you about to run ng --version OUT of your project folder ( for instance in your root HD folder). It's all to see if you have another "global" angular/cli version.

Comment: Seconding Juan's comment, the problem is that you have Angular 12 installed globally and it's somewhere in your PATH.  Try `npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular-cli`

Comment: I ran ng --version in D:\ (Root). This is what I got. Ok, I can't add it here. I have edited the question and added it there. @BrianBurton, I have already tried npm uninstall -g @angular/cli, npm cache clean, npm cache verify, npm install -g @angular/cli@9.1.15

Comment: @BrianBurton, Anyways, I still tried npm uninstall -g angular-cli (@)angular-cli and I got the message "up to date in 0.034s". So there is no angular-cli (@)angular-cli installed at global level. Any other suggestions.